# What is the mathematical structure of 2d TQFT from the 2d foam category (instead of 2d cobordism category)?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, categorification

It is well-known that the category of 2d TQFTs is equivalent to the category of commutative Frobenius algebras.

**What about functors from the 2d foam category (instead of 2d cobordism category) to the category of vector spaces?** (Here I am thinking of the foams as just abstract spaces, not embedded in any Euclidean spaces.) **Is there a similar statement as above?** i.e. do they correspond to some well-known algebraic structures?

Comment: What is the 2D foam category? A Google search only leads back to this question.

Comment: @ArunDebray Oh, I meant the category whose objects are trivalent graphs and whose morphisms are "foams" (cobordisms between trivalent graphs). So locally, a foam can look like a surface, seam, or a tetrahedral point (just like a soap bubble).

Comment: @Arun I think this notion appeared first in Khovanov's sl(3)-homology (but am somewhat ignorant of the history), and more recently Kroimer and Mrowka have defined an instanton homology for embedded trivalent graphs in $S^3$ functorial under 'foam cobordisms' in $S^3 \times I$. Their paper on this (with Tait colorings in the title) is probably a good place to look at the formal properties of these functors, but note the crucial point that these are for embedded things.

Comment: @MikeMiller That's exactly my point! I am interested in foams as abstract spaces, not as embedded things.